# spresenseのFFTスケッチについて

Tags: spresense

spresenseのMultiCore MPライブラリ内のサンプルスケッチ「AudioFFT」についてですがピーク周波数とは具体的にどういったものでしょうか。またシリアルプロッタに表示される線が基準の青線+4本の計５本なのはなぜでしょうか。初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

マイクから入力された音をFFTで周波数成分に分解したときにパワーが最大となる周波数のことですね。

参考) 例えば10kHzのsin波+ランダムノイズのデータにFFTをかけて周波数成分でみると10kHzのところにピークが現れます
https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__FrequencyBin.html

プロットが5本あるのは[マニュアル](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_mp_sample)に「MainCore で Audio ライブラリを使ってPCM 4chデータをキャプチャし SubCore へ渡します。」とあるので、マイクから4チャンネル分を入力しているからだと思います。SubFFT.inoのコードもそうなっています。

```c
      printf("24000 %8.3f %8.3f %8.3f %8.3f\n",
         peakFs[0], peakFs[1], peakFs[2], peakFs[3]);
```

一つは24000を固定で表示されていますが、48kHzサンプリングのPCMデータを入力しているのでナイキスト周波数の24kHz(上限)を表示しているのでしょう。

【追記】

MainAudio.inoを書き換えることで1chの表示(他のchは0固定表示)もできました。

```c
    /* Select mic channel number */
    const int mic_channel_num = 1;
    //const int mic_channel_num = 2;
    //const int mic_channel_num = 4;
```